# React Router v4 Redirect unit test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, react-router

How do I unit test the  component in react router v4?
I am unsuccessfully trying to unit test a simple component with a redirect using jest and enzyme.

My component:

```
 const AppContainer = ({ location }) =>
  (isUserAuthenticated()
    ? <AppWithData />
    : <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: location }
        }}
      />);
```

My attempt to test it:

```
  function setup() {
      const enzymeWrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
          <AppContainer />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );

      return {
        enzymeWrapper
      };
    }

    jest.mock("lib/authAPI", () => ({
      isUserAuthenticated: jest.fn(() => false)
    }));

    describe("AppContainer component", () => {
      it("renders redirect", () => {
        const { enzymeWrapper } = setup();

        expect(enzymeWrapper.find("<Redirect></Redirect>")).toBe(true);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Basically I'm making a shallow render of my component and verifying that if authenticated is rendering the redirect component otherwise the App one.
Here the code:

```
function setup() {
  const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<AuthenticatedApp />);

  return {
    enzymeWrapper
  };
}

describe("AuthenticatedApp component", () => {
  it("renders Redirect when user NOT autheticated", () => {
    authApi.isUserAuthenticated = jest.fn(() => false);
    const { enzymeWrapper } = setup();

    expect(enzymeWrapper.find(Redirect)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("renders AppWithData when user autheticated", () => {
    authApi.isUserAuthenticated = jest.fn(() => true);
    const { enzymeWrapper } = setup();

    expect(enzymeWrapper.find(AppWithData)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is `authApi` defined?

Answer (score 18):

Neither of these answers worked for me and took a fair bit of digging so I thought I'd chip in my experience here.

### PrivateRoute.js

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    auth.isAuthenticated
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }} />
  )} />
)
```

### PrivateRoute.spec.js

This test worked for me with no problems whatsoever, it rendered the `PrivateComponent` when `auth.isAuthenticated` evaluated to true.

```
it('renders the component when the user is authorised', () => {
  auth.login()
  expect(auth.isAuthenticated).toBe(true)
  const privateRoute = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/privateComponent']}>
      <PrivateRoute path='/privateComponent' component={PrivateComponent} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
  expect(privateRoute.find('PrivateComponent').length).toEqual(1)
})
```

This was the test that gave me a lot of issues. At first I was checking for the `Redirect` component.

I tried to just do something like

```
expect(privateRoute.find('Redirect').length).toEqual(1)
```

But that just wouldn't work, no matter what I did, it just couldn't find the `Redirect` component. In the end, I ended up checking the history but couldn't find any reliable documentation online and ended up looking at the React Router codebase.

In [MemoryRouter.js (line 30)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/MemoryRouter.js#L30) I saw that it rendered a [`Router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js) component. I noticed that it was also passing it's `history` as a prop to `Router` so I figured I would be able to grab it from there.

I ended up grabbing the history prop from `Router` using `privateRoute.find('Router').prop('history')` which then finally gave me evidence that a redirect had actually happened, to the correct location, no less.

```
it('renders a redirect when the user is not authorised', () => {
  auth.logout()
  expect(auth.isAuthenticated).toBe(false)
  const privateRoute = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/privateComponent']}>
      <PrivateRoute path='/privateComponent' component={PrivateComponent} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
  expect(privateRoute.find('PrivateComponent').length).toEqual(0)
  expect(
    privateRoute.find('Router').prop('history').location.pathname
  ).toEqual('/')
})
```

With this test, you're testing the actual functionality of the `PrivateRoute` component and ensuring that it goes where it's saying it's going.

The documentation leaves a lot to be desired. For example, it took a fair bit of digging for me to find out about `initialEntries` as a prop for `MemoryRouter`, you need this so it actually hits the route and executes the conditional, I spent too long trying to cover both branches only to realise this was what was needed.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Excellent Answer very helpful!

Comment: this is my route. `<Route path="/security/exemptions/user" component={() => (<Redirect to="/user/exemptions" /> )} />`

Comment: actually this works `expect(wrapper.find(Router).prop('history').location.pathname).toEqual('/user/exemptions');`. but not this line `expect(wrapper.find(Redirect)).toHaveLength(1);`

Comment: Yep, that's what my answer says.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my minimal example of testing that the actual URL changes instead of just that a `Redirect` component exists on the page:

`RedirectApp.js`:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const RedirectApp = props => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect from="/all-courses" to="/courses" />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default RedirectApp;
```

`RedirectApp.test.js`:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import RedirectApp from "./RedirectApp";

it("redirects /all-courses to /courses", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[`/all-courses`]}>
      <Route component={RedirectApp} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  expect(wrapper.find(RedirectApp).props().location.pathname).toBe("/courses");
});
```

By wrapping `RedirectApp` in a `Route`, `MemoryRouter` injects the `react-router` props (`match`, `location`, and `history`) in `RedirectApp`.

`enzyme` lets you grab these `props()`, and the `location` prop includes the `pathname` after redirect, so the redirected location can be matched.

This method is a little hacky, but has the advantage of testing that a redirect is going to the *correct* place and not just that a `Redirect` exists.

Alternatively, you can `export default withRouter(RedirectApp)` in `RedirectApp.js` to automatically get the `react-router` props injected.